# Using “OR” in SQL

Tags: query, ms-access-2016

I am new to sql and today my manager asked me to retrieve some customres informations using their customer ID so i used the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustID = “11023” or CustID = “11045” or CustID = “11001” or CustID = “101989”;
```

It did work but i wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: "better way to do it" -- better in what way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Better* is a relative term as different people will have different opinions got different engines. That said, a *simpler* method to search for multiple records using the same column would be `IN`. Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Customers
 WHERE CustID IN ("11023", "11045", "11001", "101989");
```

This makes it a little easier to write queries that can look up any number of customers by ID.